# prefix namespace variability and xlst

Tags: xml, xslt

The prefix namespace of my xml may vary depending on the source, but not the structure.
for exemple sometimes I have`"t:" prefix

```
 <t:DICT>
    <t:noConsultationDuTeleservice>2015071717689S</t:noConsultationDuTeleservice>
    <t:noAffaireDeLexecutantDesTravaux>2015/181/A</t:noAffaireDeLexecutantDesTravaux>
</t:DICT>
```

`from an other source it is a "d:" prefix

```
<d:DICT>
    <d:noConsultationDuTeleservice>2015071717689S</d:noConsultationDuTeleservice>
    <d:noAffaireDeLexecutantDesTravaux>2015/181/A</d:noAffaireDeLexecutantDesTravaux>
</d:DICT>
```

How to adapt my xslt in the select to remove namespace`<xsl:value-of select ="DICT/noConsultationDuTeleservice"/>` ?

Comment: Do not confuse the namespace *prefix* with the namespace.  The latter is identified by the URI bound to the prefix in the scope where the prefix is used.  XSLT understands this.  Thus, your source documents can use any namespace prefix they like, as long as it is bound to the correct URI (which your XSLT also references).  That is likely the case you're dealing with, but if not, then please clarify with a [mcve].

Comment: ok I understand, but How this helps me here ?

Comment: Ok I have verified the uri are similar
But how to play with different prefixes ?

Comment: @ericire The prefix used by the source XML plays no role in the XSL transformation. Define your own prefix, bind it to the namespace URI, and use it in your XSLT.

Comment: XSLT (XPath, really) does not match names based on prefixes, it matches them based on the local part and namespace URI.  If the namespace URIs are the same then you don't have to do anything special to treat the elements the same.

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete XML samples, including any namespace declarations. As for using `<xsl:value-of select ="DICT/noConsultationDuTeleservice"/>`, unless you can use an XSLT 2.0 or later processor like Saxon 9, XmlPrime, Altova where you could use `xpath-default-namespace`, there is no XSLT way of avoiding the use of a prefix. So please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, you must not confuse namespace *prefixes* with namespaces themselves, which are abstract entities principally identified by URIs.  Namespaces and their identifying URIs are universal; namespace prefixes are document specific.  Even within a single document, different namespace prefixes may correspond to the same namespace (as judged by whether they are bound to the same namespace URI).  Their significance to XSLT is limited to their association with a particular namespace URI.

You present examples of input elements with the same local names but different namespace prefixes.  These elements should appear within the scope of a namespace declaration associated with their respective prefixes, otherwise the source documents do not comply with XML Namespaces.  Furthermore, the fact that you rely on the local parts of the element names to have the same significance for both prefixes is, in effect, an assertion that you expect the prefixes are associated with the *same* namespace.

XSLT, via XPath, matches nodes not by the qualified names appearing literally in the document, but rather by their *expanded names*, which are ordered pairs consisting of their possibly-null namespace ***URI*** and the local part of their qualified name.  Thus, the differing namespace prefixes in the input documents are irrelevant; what matters is the namespace URI to which each prefix is bound.

On the other hand, because XSLT matches nodes by expanded name, your XSLT does need to account for the non-null namespace to which the source documents' element names belong.  You would do this in XSLT 1.0 by declaring your own namespace prefix for that namespace in your stylesheet, so that it is in scope where the expressions involving those names appear, and by using appropriately-prefixed names in your expressions.

For example, given this source document:

```
<d:root xmlns:d="http://some.organization.com/Namespace">
<d:DICT>
  <d:noConsultationDuTeleservice>2015071717689S</d:noConsultationDuTeleservice>
  <d:noAffaireDeLexecutantDesTravaux>2015/181/A</d:noAffaireDeLexecutantDesTravaux>
</d:DICT>
</d:root>
```

You might write XSLT such as this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns="http://some.organization.com/Namespace">

  <xsl:template match="ns:root">
    <noConsultation>
      <xsl:value-of select="ns:DICT/ns:noConsultationDuTeleservice"/>
    </noConsultation>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That will work equally well for an input document that uses a different prefix for the same namespace, such as

```
<t:root xmlns:t="http://some.organization.com/Namespace">
<t:DICT>
  <t:noConsultationDuTeleservice>2015071717689S</t:noConsultationDuTeleservice>
  <t:noAffaireDeLexecutantDesTravaux>2015/181/A</t:noAffaireDeLexecutantDesTravaux>
</t:DICT>
</t:root>
```

Comment: It seems that it is not working with the same xslt and that it is why I post here
I explain in other response

Comment: Ok it works now.
I did not notice that the version of the namespace was different and therefore it did not work.
I have to extract the version of the uri from the namespace to see if it has evolved compared to that of my xslt